# Tinyproxy and Proxyfier combination

Tags: proxy

I have a VPS with Tinyproxy installed, and I have my PC configured with Proxyfier. Protocols SOCKSv4 and SOCKSv5 doesn't work for me, and I need HTTPS protocol. But when I choose HTTPS protocol I'm getting this error:

```
43:04] Error : the proxy server cannot establish connection with www.google.com:80
    The error may indicate that the proxy server doesn't support SSL connections.
    It means that the proxy can be used for web browsing but it cannot work with Proxifier.
    The proxy server reply header is:
        HTTP/1.0 403 Access violation
        Server: tinyproxy/1.8.3
        Content-Type: text/html
        Connection: close
[43:04] Test failed.
```

Could you suggest me a possible solution? Maybe another program that work's like Proxifier or another Proxy that support https authentication and easy to get working.